# Scala BigDecimal fails to translate a decimal String representation created by itself

Tags: java, scala, bigdecimal

While playing around with generative testing I came across the following:

```
import org.scalacheck.Properties
import org.scalacheck.Prop.forAll

object BigDecimalSpec extends Properties("BigDecimal") {
  property("apply") = forAll(Arbitrary.arbBigDecimal.arbitrary) {
    x => x == BigDecimal(x.toString())
  }
}
```

fails with:

```
! String.apply: Exception raised on property evaluation.
> ARG_0: 0E+2147483648
> Exception: java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:511)
java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:757)
scala.math.BigDecimal$.apply(BigDecimal.scala:119)
scala.math.BigDecimal$.apply(BigDecimal.scala:117)
```

Why wouldn't `BigDecimal` be able to translate a decimal `String` representation created by itself?

Comment: This BigDecimal value is weird, it's actually zero, written rather convolutedly. How was this value constructed?

Comment: @laune, it was constructed by `Arbitrary.arbBigDecimal.arbitrary` which is a `scalacheck` generator for `scala.math.BigDecimal`

Comment: Perhaps this code doesn't try to stay within "reasonable" bounds. A number of this size isn't realistic - compare it to the number of atoms in the universe...

Comment: Since tests test the unreasonable by definition, how about this: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9143

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by definition. From BigDecimal's javadoc:

The exponent consists of the character 'e' ('\u0065') or 'E' ('\u0045') followed by one or more decimal digits. The value of the exponent must lie between -Integer.MAX_VALUE (Integer.MIN_VALUE+1) and **Integer.MAX_VALUE,** inclusive.

Emphasis by me, and Integer.MAX_VALUE = 2147483647.

Comment: I would emphasize the other clause, because that is what is violated.

Comment: @som-snytt The exponent E+2147483648 is one beyond MAX_VALUE.

Comment: @som-snytt "Some of us...": That's why I put it in boldface.